# Update the first record from each group

Tags: mysql

There is a table with 5 columns: `id`, `data`, `category`, `time`, `page`.
I want to get rows where `id` > `given id` and `category` = `given category`, group them by `page`, get the first from each page ordered by `time` and decrement `page` column in that rows. (The `time` isn't unique)

I managed to create this query and it works but i wonder if there is any better solution.
I also had a problem with choosing appropriate question title, so feel free to correct me if you think it's not exactly what it should be.

```
UPDATE `content` AS TABLE1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(TABLE2.`id`) AS ID, TABLE2.`page` FROM `content` AS TABLE2
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT `page`, MIN(`time`) AS MINTIME
            FROM `content` 
            WHERE (`page` > (SELECT `page` FROM `content` WHERE `id` = ?) AND `category` = ?)
            GROUP BY `page`) AS TABLE3
        ON TABLE2.`page` = TABLE3.`page` AND TABLE2.`time` = TABLE3.MINTIME
        GROUP BY TABLE2.`page`) AS TABLE4
    ON TABLE1.`id` = TABLE4.ID
SET TABLE1.`page` = TABLE1.`page` - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this.  You don't need the @ variable but I didn't want to use question marks in the SQL:

```
SET @id:= <given id>;

UPDATE
  content c1 LEFT JOIN content c2 ON c1.page = c2.page AND 
                                     c1.category = c2.category AND 
                                     c2.time < c1.time AND c2.id > @id
SET c1.page=c1.page-1
WHERE 
  c1.id > @id AND
  c2.id IS NULL AND
  c1.category = '<given category>';
```